# Database permissions issues since migration to new SQL server

Tags: permissions, database

I moved my SQL server from the server hosting Sharepoint to another server. Since then, I've had db permission errors (ex.

```
Insufficient SQL database permissions for user 'Name: domain\sp2013_farm SID: S-1-5-21-3144544779-1869488410-2151655755-1609 ImpersonationLevel: Impersonation' in database 'SharePoint_AdminContent_7b914aee-c2ae-4651-8760-ff3b6b27d222' on SQL Server instance 'infostore\infostore'. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Sec_SiteGroupsView', database 'SharePoint_AdminContent_7b914aee-c2ae-4651-8760-ff3b6b27d222', schema 'dbo'.`
```

I've verified that my farm account has `db_owner` access to that db, so I'm not sure what else to check.

This error happens when I try to open site settings `http://centraladministration/_layouts/15/people.aspx`. 
I'm getting similar permissions errors when trying to access search crawl settings. 
`http://centraladministration/_admin/search/crawlhealthreports.aspx` & `http://centraladministration/_admin/search/queryhealthreports.aspx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just recreating the SSA.

Answer (score 0):

Your farm account is not a SQL Login account.

So you dont need to use login and password, just specify the database server and then click OK.

Comment: where to specify the database server? I added the farm account as a sql login account?